# Openpyxl - how to populate data on specific sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl for the first time. I have to read excel file, then after manipulation, populate the result on three different excel sheets -> sheet_T, sheet_D and sheet_U. I created three sheets using openpyxl as follows-

```
sheet_T = filename2.create_sheet(0) 
sheet_T.title = "Target First" 
sheet_D = filename2.create_sheet(1) 
sheet_D.title = "Distractor First" 
sheet_U = filename2.create_sheet(2) 
sheet_U.title = "Unclassified"
```

---

I used xlwt to do it but there is a constraint of 256 columns. Hence, I used openpyxl. The below code is written by using xlwt-

```
sheet_T.write(row_first, col_target, Name_Target)
sheet_D.write(row_first, col_target, Name_Target)
sheet_U.write(row_first, col_target, Name_Target)
```

How do I write the same thing by using openpyxl? All the documentation I read is how to write on a specific cell not sheet.

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another sheet:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import ExcelWriter

wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.worksheets[0]
ws0.title = 'My Sheet 1'
ws1 = wb.create_sheet()
ws1.title = 'My Sheet 2'
ws2 = wb.create_sheet()
ws2.title = 'My Sheet 3'
```

Now you can write to the different sheets:

```
cell_ws0_a1 = ws0.cell('A1')
cell_ws0_a1.value = 'Wrote to cell in 1st sheet.'

cell_ws1_a1 = ws1.cell('A1')
cell_ws1_a1.value = 'Wrote to cell in 2nd sheet.'

cell_ws2_a1 = ws2.cell('A1')
cell_ws2_a1.value = 'Wrote to cell in 3rd sheet.'

writer = ExcelWriter(workbook=wb)
writer.save('example.xlsx')
```

There is only one sheet in a workbook by default. `wb.create_sheet()` creates a second sheet.

Comment: I don't think I need to create sheet. I have an excel file, there three sheets have to be created. Depending on the criteria, data has to be written either on any one of the sheet

Comment: You are creating a new Excel file with your output, right? Per default `openpyxl` creates only one sheet. Did you try out my answer?

Comment: Thanks Mike for your help. I'm getting an error while retrieving data from excel sheet. wb             = load_workbook(filename, use_iterators=True)
sheet          = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

print 'Value = ', sheet.cell(row =1, column =1).value

Comment: It is returning me None value. Please guide me.

Comment: Does the writing work? Your comment is about reading while this question is about writing. Did you open the created file in Excel?

Comment: Yes Mike - I'm trying to read data from Target Excel sheet, then make calculations and after that populate the result onto Destination (new) excel file on three different sheets. But unfortunately, my program is not reading the data from the Target Excel sheet. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a correction in the code for smooth running-

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import ExcelWriter

wb = Workbook()
ws0 = wb.worksheets[0]
ws0.title = 'My Sheet 1'
ws1 = wb.create_sheet()
ws1.title = 'My Sheet 2'
ws2 = wb.create_sheet()
ws2.title = 'My Sheet 3

v1 = ws1.cell(row=1, column=1)
v1.value = "Hello"
```

(Basically insert values in this manner instead)
And then end with-

```
writer = ExcelWriter(wb, 'file.xlsx')
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Hope this helps :)